# Material-UI Table pagination translation

Tags: material-ui

I'm trying to translate the table pagination of a material ui table. The guy from MUI said it's somehow possible ([issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/17170)).

So does anybody knows how to translate to **of** from the displayed rows label `${from}-${to} of ${count}`

Answer (score 8):

You can set 'labelDisplayedRows' of TablePagination

```
<TablePagination
  ...
  labelDisplayedRows={
    ({ from, to, count }) => {
      return '' + from + '-' + to + ' из ' + count
    }
  }
/>
```

More properties in docs: https://material-ui.com/ru/api/table-pagination/